# Cannot upgrade android in-app subscription. Error: "Something went wrong on our end. Please try again."

Tags: android, in-app-billing, play-billing-library

### Issue:

- Cannot upgrade current subscription to different subscription.
- Showing Error: "Something went wrong on our end. Please try again."

### Description:

- Were using `play billing library v3.0.3` and we handled subscription upgrade as code below.

```java
BillingFlowParams purchaseParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                    .setSkuDetails(skuDetails)
                    .setOldSku(oldSKU, oldPurchaseToken)
                    .setReplaceSkusProrationMode(IMMEDIATE_WITH_TIME_PRORATION)
                    .build();
```

- Things were as expected when we launched.
- Some users reported that they cannot upgrade their subscription.
- We tested upgrade and same error was encountered: *"Something went wrong on our end. Please try again."*
- **Then we upgraded to `play billing library v4.0.0`** thinking it would solve our issue.

```java
BillingFlowParams billingFlowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
        .setSubscriptionUpdateParams(SubscriptionUpdateParams.newBuilder()
            .setOldSkuPurchaseToken(oldPurchaseToken)
            .setOldSkuPurchaseId(oldSKU) // This method is not available in lib[4.0.0] but mentioned in docs
            .setReplaceSkusProrationMode(IMMEDIATE_WITH_TIME_PRORATION))
        .setSkuDetails(skuDetails)
        .build();
```

- Same error is reported again: *"Something went wrong on our end. Please try again."*
- *Also new `play billing library v4.0.0` does not have method setOldSkuPurchaseId() in class  SubscriptionUpdateParams.Builder but mentioned in [developer docs](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/subscriptions#proration)*

**Error Screenshot Attached Below**

[image: screenshot]

Comment: facing same issue on 3.0.3 , did upgrading to 4.0.0 solved this for you ?

Comment: @SourinGhosh No, it did not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Due to the new [Reserve Bank of India eMandate notification](https://www.rbi.org.in/Scripts/NotificationUser.aspx?Id=12051&Mode=0) some of your subscription experiences may change.**

For More Details [checkout this](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/9818348?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid)

Answer (score 3):

I had to add an additional .build() to Google's example code

```
        // Retrieve a value for "skuDetails" by calling querySkuDetailsAsync()
        val flowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                .setSubscriptionUpdateParams(SubscriptionUpdateParams.newBuilder()
                    .setOldSkuPurchaseToken(purchaseTokenOfOriginalSubscription)
                    .setReplaceSkusProrationMode(desiredProrationMode)
                    .build() // <-- MISSING BUILD
                    )
                .setSkuDetails(upgradeOrDowngradeSkuDetails)
                .build();
        val responseCode = billingClient.launchBillingFlow(activity, flowParams)
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. I'm more surprised that Google didn't show this in any documentation ... how can they be so ridiculously careless.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get rid of the error "Something went wrong on our end. Please try again." I cleared the Play Market cache and rebooted the device.

**Update:**
I found a solution. Just skip this parameter, don't specify it. It works well with subscriptions in my app.

```
.setOldSkuPurchaseId(previousSku)
```

Comment: Have you verified that previous subscription is NOT active?

Comment: @TejPratap Yes. I checked my app in the subscriptions section of the Play Market.

Comment: I don't even see `setOldSkuPurchaseId`