# Getting "ERROR" when using specific proration modes for upgrading/downgrading a subscription

Tags: android, in-app-subscription, play-billing-library

I am using the Google Play Billing library version 4.0.0

I have followed the integration docs: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate & created subscription plans in the Google Play console.

There are two monthly subscription plans:

1. pro1_monthly (₹140.01)
2. pro2_monthly (₹210.02)

I purchase `pro1_monthly` first normally like so:

```java
BillingFlowParams billingFlowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                    .setSkuDetails(pro1MonthlySkuDetails)
                    .build();
// and launch the billing flow
billingClient.launchBillingFlow(this, billingFlowParams);
```

Next I purchase the `pro2_monthly`. Here only the `IMMEDIATE_AND_CHARGE_PRORATED_PRICE` & `IMMEDIATE_AND_CHARGE_FULL_PRICE` mode is working for me.

The other modes give the error with billing response code 5 which is described in the documentation as `DEVELOPER_ERROR`. I have attached the screenshot of the error. And this is the code for upgrade/downgrade:

```java
// Retrieve a value for "skuDetails" by calling querySkuDetailsAsync().
BillingFlowParams billingFlowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                                     .setSubscriptionUpdateParams(BillingFlowParams.SubscriptionUpdateParams.newBuilder()
                      .setOldSkuPurchaseToken(pro1MonthlyPurchaseToken)    
                      .setReplaceSkusProrationMode(BillingFlowParams.ProrationMode.IMMEDIATE_WITH_TIME_PRORATION)
                            .build())
                    .setSkuDetails(pro2MonthlySkuDetails)
                    .build();
            int responseCode = billingClient.launchBillingFlow(this, billingFlowParams).getResponseCode();
            System.out.println("pro2_monthly: " + responseCode);
```

```
pro2_monthly: 5 // billing response code
```

[screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mj5tF.png)

Here is a link to a related post [Cannot upgrade android in-app subscription. Error: "Something went wrong on our end. Please try again."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67689804/cannot-upgrade-android-in-app-subscription-error-something-went-wrong-on-our)

I am testing this from India region. I want to understand why `IMMEDIATE_AND_CHARGE_PRORATED_PRICE` & `IMMEDIATE_AND_CHARGE_FULL_PRICE` mode is working. Because  these modes display the dialog to change the subscription and perform the upgrade with no issues.

But the other modes `IMMEDIATE_WITH_TIME_PRORATION`, `IMMEDIATE_WITHOUT_PRORATION`,  & `DEFERRED` do not work for upgrade/downgrade.

**Lastly**

I have verified the common issues like app version name, version code, APK signing, billing enabled, purchase token verification, acknowledging purchases, using queryPurchasesAsync oldSkuDetails(pro1MonthlySkuPurchaseToken) for subscription update, & enablingPendingPurchases.

**Billing result debug message:** The subscription can't have the first charge for free.

**Subscription options set in play console:**

- Monthly plan with free trial disabled
- Grace period 7 days
- Introductory price selected as none
- Resubscribe is enabled for all