# User specific "Something went wrong on our end. Please try again"

Tags: android, google-play, play-billing-library

This is extremely frustrating as we have clients that are raging that they are losing sales and we don't have a definite answer. Google really needs to do better with their messaging.

[image]

Our app has in-app subscriptions, and many of our users have no problems subscribing... except for a small percentage of them. Which is a big loss of thousands of dollars.

But it works for everyone else. Which implies it is a user specific problem.

We've asked customers to do the usual "restart", "clear cache", "reinstall", etc. to no avail. They also claim that they can subscribe to other applications on the Play Store but we have no way of verifying.

So far there doesn't seem to be any correlation between operating system version, or device.

Everything we read about this topic implies it is a user specific problem. But our client will not accept this as an answer.

How can we help these people?

Comment: Have you checked this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67689804/cannot-upgrade-android-in-app-subscription-error-something-went-wrong-on-our

Comment: Yes we have come across this post and we have no reason to believe there is any issues with the code, given that the majority of customers are subscribing fine. And yes, the "build()" calls are there.